# Redirect page in Laravel after saving

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller

I am an beginner for Laravel, just to know what went wrong as after I saved my data from the form, it will redirect me to an index page, which was want from beginning then only I am able to view my quotation details. But right now what I need is that after adding new quotation, I need it to redirect me to the quotation details straight away.

```
return view('bd.quotation.index', compact('quotations'));
```

This is the part where I put it to redirect me to the quotations index.

```
redirect('/bd/quotation/{id}'); // type 1 

function showQuotation($id) {
    return view('bd.quotation.quotationItem', compact('customers','quotations','quotationItems','quotationIT' ));
}
```

Type 1 I tried, it's not working. It will show me a blank page and the second one isn't working as well.

```
public function quotationItem($id)
{
    $quotations= Quotation::where('id', $id)->first();   
    $customers = Customer::where('id', $quotations->cust_id)->first();
    $quotationIT = QuotationIT::where('quotation_number', $quotations->item_name)->first();
    $quotationItems = QuotationItem::where('quotation_number', $id)->get();
    
    return view('bd.quotation.quotationItem', compact('customers','quotations','quotationItems','quotationIT' ));
}
```

This is the code where I able to see my quotation details.

Comment: your question is confusing and unclear.. what do you want actually?? redirect to the view page after creating a new entry??

Comment: Creating a qoutation and then redirect to another page with that newly created entry, you need to list that data on the index page and whenever you redirect it will show you the data. It's a simple scenario I don't know why you aren't picking it up.

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is that you didnt return redirect

so change: `redirect('/bd/quotation/{id}');`

to `return redirect('/bd/quotation/{id}');`

there are 3 steps to redirect:

1- is to return redirect function in controller after saving your data:

```
return redirect('your-url');
```

2-make route for that in web.php:

```
 Route::get('your-url', 'YourController@yourFunction');
```

3-writing yourFunction:

```
 public function yourFunction()
{
    return "you are here";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to redirect with id, I think this way will help you

return redirect()->route('a_newsEvents',['id'=>$id]);